# How do I allocate more memory to node.js when running ng build? (Mac)

Tags: node.js, angular

I have started to experience node crashes during `ng build --prod`, due to increasing memory requirements of my angular-cli app. I have seen solutions like this:

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 myAwesomeServer.js
```

but how could that be applied to `ng` commands (esp. `ng bundle`)?

Answer (score 8):

You allowed to setup node command line options through environment variable:

```
NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096 ng bundle
```

https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_options_options

also you allowed to run ng like

```
node --max-old-space-size=2048 $(which ng) bundle # not tested by myself
```

Comment: Why do you think that `ng` uses these parameters? They are for `node` process. `ng` uses only [these parameters](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#options)

Comment: NODE_OPTIONS environment variable read by node process itself. Node process actually executes `ng` (see ng's shebang - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/bin/ng - invocation of `ng` executes node in current environment with source code of `ng` script).

Comment: ```node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/bin/ionic-app-scripts.js build --release --prod --minifyjs --minifycss --optimizejs ```

Comment: I have the same question but I am trying to set this value from a docker-compose.   What do i put in the compose file to make RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --prod not run out of memory

Comment: @JohnBowyer did you ever figure this out?  just ran into the same problem

Comment: Robin, I was not able to find a solution.