# How do I allocate more memory to node.js when running ng build in docker?

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, docker-compose

I have started to experience node crashes during ng build --prod, due to increasing memory requirements of my angular-cli app. I have seen solutions like this:

[Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46115463/how-do-i-allocate-more-memory-to-node-js-when-running-ng-build-mac)

However, I am unsure how to configure this change in docker.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:11.6.0-alpine AS builder
COPY . ./visualizationadmin-ng
WORKDIR /visualizationadmin-ng
RUN npm i
RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --aot --prod

FROM nginx:1.15.8-alpine
RUN chmod g+rwx /var/cache/nginx /var/run /var/log/nginx
COPY --from=builder /visualizationadmin-ng/dist/visualizationadmin-ng/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# OpenShift port
EXPOSE 8080
```

Docker-compose

```
version: '2.3'

services:
  angular:
    hostname: localhost
    container_name: visualizationadmin-ng
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      NODE_OPTIONS: ${NODE_OPTIONS}
```

.env file

```
NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096 ng bundle
```

When I run docker-compose I get the following error log

<--- Last few GCs --->

[1:0x563fd8b258c0]   259664 ms: Mark-sweep 1174.6 (1443.6) -> 1162.0 (1447.6) MB, 1332.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.206, current mu = 0.112) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[1:0x563fd8b258c0]   260886 ms: Mark-sweep 1177.1 (1447.6) -> 1161.6 (1448.1) MB, 1170.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.133, current mu = 0.042) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed

```
<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x16812784fb5d]
Security context: 0x2ae71059d921 <JSObject>
    1: yn(aka yn) [0x7a102207399] [/visualizationadmin-ng/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:~1] [pc=0x16812b2f9406](this=0x29a3dc8025b1 <undefined>,0x29a3dc8025b1 <undefined>)
    2: /* anonymous */ [0x7a102203919] [/visualizationadmin-ng/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:~1] [pc=0x16812b1b0471](this=0x128f61ced9d9 <AST_SymbolRef map = 0x3eb1d6dae2...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
ERROR: Service 'angular' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c $(npm bin)/ng build --aot --prod' returned a non-zero code: 139
```

The docker fails both locally and in gitlab ci/cd.   My local docker configuration settings are attached.

[image]

Comment: You probably need to check the agent you're running your build on.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by agent.  I am running this in docker desktop and I added the settings.  What specifically should I check to resolve the issue?

Comment: You've shown a screenshot of the configuration dialog, what happens when you increase memory to something like 10G?